# RubyMotion UITableView dataSource not returning properly

Tags: ios, rubymotion

I’m new to [RubyMotion](http://www.rubymotion.com). With this controller:

```
class LectureController < UIViewController


    def viewDidLoad
        super

        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor

        @lectures ||= []

        Lecture.get() do |success, lectures|
            if success
                @lectures = lectures
                p "Received #{@lectures.length} lectures"
                @table.reloadData
            else
                App.alert("OOPS!")
            end
        end


        @table = UITableView.alloc.initWithFrame(self.view.bounds)
        self.view.addSubview @table
        @table.dataSource = self


        def tableView(tableView, numberOfRowsInSection: section)
            @lectures.count
        end

        def tableView(tableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)
            @reuseIdentifier ||= "CELL_IDENTIFIER"

            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(@reuseIdentifier) || begin
                UITableViewCell.alloc.initWithStyle(UITableViewCellStyleDefault, reuseIdentifier: @reuseIdentifier)
            end

            cell.textLabel.text = @lectures[indexPath.row].name

            cell
        end


    end

    def initWithNibName(name, bundle: bundle)
        super
        self.title = "Lectures"
        self
    end

end
```

I’m running into the following error message:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException',
reason: 'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from
tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:'
```

As far as I can see, `cellForRowAtIndexPath` should *be* returning a cell. I can’t figure out why it won’t work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could it be the stray "end" within cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: Nope, that's part of the `cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(@reuseIdentifier) || begin
                UITableViewCell.alloc.initWithStyle(UITableViewCellStyleDefault, reuseIdentifier: @reuseIdentifier)
            end` block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your two `tableView` methods are nested under your `viewDidLoad` method. They should be moved out to be part of the main `LectureController` class.

In a typical Ruby class you may be able to get away with this (where calling the `viewDidLoad` method dynamically defines the other methods), but it won't work in RubyMotion due to the way the code is converted/compiled.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know this about Rubymotion before! :D

Comment: Even in a regular ruby program you shouldn't do this (even though you can), because you'll get warnings about "already defined methods" each successive time you run `viewDidLoad`.